# Duplicate "keys" in map-reduce output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As we all know, either this

```
public static class SReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
     {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (key.hasNext()) 
            {
                sb.append(key.next().toString());   
            }
            output.collect(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }

     }
```

or

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {
            boolean start = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (values.hasNext()) 
            {
                if(!start)
                {
                start=false;
                sb.append(values.next().toString());
                }           
            }
            output.collect(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }
    }
```

this, is the kind of reducer function we use to eliminate duplicate "values" in output. But what should I do to eliminate duplicate "keys"? Any idea?
Thanks.

PS: more info : In my < key,values > pairs, keys contain links and values contain words. But in my output, each word occurs only once, but I get many duplicate links.

Comment: In what sense do these `Reducer`s eliminate duplicate values? I'd think there's a `Set` in there somewhere to do that. The first outputs all values, or tries to -- you have at least two typos. The second will actually print nothing; I don't know what the intent was. Neither does anything like eliminate duplicate values.

Comment: Admissions   www.cs.unic.edu/admissionswww.cs.unic.edu/admissions

Comment: just like the links above are duplicates, this is the problem im facing!

Comment: Give a complete example, what are your values, in which format do you want the output? And most importantly what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

In the `Reducer`, there will be one call to `reduce()` for each unique key that the `Reducer` receives. It will receive all values for that key. But if you only care about the keys, and only care about unique keys, well, just ignore the values entirely. You will get exactly one `reduce()` per key; do whatever you want with that (non-duplicated) key.

Comment: What do you mean by ignore the values? You mean I should remove the reducer?

Comment: Ignore in this context means don't use them.

Comment: No, I want the values, but I don't have to reduce them as they are already unique, I just have to process the keys to avoid duplicates.

Comment: You don't ever have duplicate keys in the `Reducer` to begin with... I am not sure what you are talking about.